# Libraries to convert HashMap to printable form

Tags: hashmap, libraries

I know you can use an iterator to print the map, but are there perhaps any libraries or methods that offer a way to print a HashMap in a nice, readable way?

Answer (score 0):

Here, I wrote a quick method for you. Makes maps very easy to read.

```
public static <K,V> void printMap(Map<K,V> map){

    for(K key : map.keySet())
        System.out.println("Key: " + k + "  ||  Value: " + map.get(k));

}
```

This will work for any type of key `<K>` and type of value `<V>`.